# Getting decision tree like rules for my cluster(s)

Tags: clustering, decision-trees, k-means

After performing clustering and detailed cluster analysis, I am confident that my clusters make sense.

Now, for each cluster, I would like to generate rules in the form of decision tree output. With this, I intend to achieve two things:

1. Most significant variables
2. Most significant combinations of variables which lead to the cluster

I do not want to perform decision tree classification with K clusters as K classes and instead obtain rules for the population which is already segmented. Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you don't like the idea of training a (shallow) Decision Tree model with your clusters as labels, and using those rules?

Comment: Firstly, it will create class imbalance problems as all my classes do not have equal number of members. Secondly, the maximum accuracy that I am achieving with a max_depth 5 is 34%. At this accuracy, I believe the bins are not useful. Thirdly, since my clusters already look meaningful, I do not want to spend time in training a decision tree. I just want an automated way of generating the rules from the feature values representing each cluster.

Answer (score 1):

> I do not want to perform decision tree classification with K clusters as K classes

You should.

A tree is a representation of rules in which you follow a path which begins in the root node and ends in every leaf node.

If the tree separates between `x<=30` and `x>30`, then the rules are:

```
If x<=30 then
    Follow path A
Else:
    Follow Path B
```

Comment: I did this and the best accuracy I am getting is 34%. I am afraid I cannot trust the rules generated by this model.

Answer (score 1):

This almost sounds like a combination of supervised learning and unsupervised learning.  Consider finding significant features that predict a target variable like this (fee in your own data).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# matplotlib inline

df = pd.read_csv("https://rodeo-tutorials.s3.amazonaws.com/data/credit-data-trainingset.csv")
df.head()

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

features = np.array(['revolving_utilization_of_unsecured_lines',
                     'age', 'number_of_time30-59_days_past_due_not_worse',
                     'debt_ratio', 'monthly_income','number_of_open_credit_lines_and_loans', 
                     'number_of_times90_days_late', 'number_real_estate_loans_or_lines',
                     'number_of_time60-89_days_past_due_not_worse', 'number_of_dependents'])
clf = RandomForestClassifier()
clf.fit(df[features], df['serious_dlqin2yrs'])

# from the calculated importances, order them from most to least important
# and make a barplot so we can visualize what is/isn't important
importances = clf.feature_importances_
sorted_idx = np.argsort(importances)


padding = np.arange(len(features)) + 0.5
plt.barh(padding, importances[sorted_idx], align='center')
plt.yticks(padding, features[sorted_idx])
plt.xlabel("Relative Importance")
plt.title("Variable Importance")
plt.show()
```

[image]

When you have your best features selected, consider applying KMeans, AffinityPropagation, Mean Shift, SpectralClustering, AgglomerativeClustering, or DBSCAN.  See the link below for more details.

[Comparing Python Clustering Algorithms | The hdbscan Clustering Library](https://hdbscan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/comparing_clustering_algorithms.html)